# Is there a difference between singular values of a kernel and its associated integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, singular-values

Suppose we have a square integrable kernel $K_A(s,t)$. Define the integral operator $A:H \rightarrow H_A$, where $H,H_A$ are Hilbert spaces, by $$Ah = \int_{\Omega_s}K_A(s,t)h(s)ds,$$ for all $h\in H$. Are the singular values of the kernel $K_A$ and the operator $A$ defined to be the same? I cannot find a conclusive answer. References are appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "singular values of the kernel"?  Singular values are normally only aspects of the linear operator.

Comment: @BrianBorchers , In several papers I am reading, they express the kernel as an infinite summation. i.e. $$K_A = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_i u_i(s). v_i(t)$$ I am not clear if these are the same as the singular values of the operator $A$.